# Regular expression in C# for currency conversions from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm making my own assistant in C# that accepts different kinds of phrases and i want to validate this kind of strings for currency conversion:

"20 $ to euro"
"125 mkd to dollars"
"30 euro to mkd"
"30 mkd to $"

etc.

I don't want every currency in the world, i only need mkd,euro,$,dollars.
Also if there's a way so i can easily parse the string into 3 parts: value,firstUnit,secondUnit so i can easily do the math after parsing it, it would be great.

Comment: Well have you tried using string `Split` and then work on the individual values ! !

Comment: `(\d+) (mkd|euro|\$|dollars) to (mkd|euro|\$|dollars)` should work - group 1 is your value, group 2 is first unit, group 3 is second unit.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, this works great. Btw @Dennis i haven't used regular expressions very much and i just wanted to see an example for finding substrings like (euro|dollar|mkd) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
(?<value>\d+) (?<currency>[^\s]+) to (?<targetcurrency>[^\s]+)
```

Then use in c# like so:

```
//remember to escape the '\' characters
var regex = "(?<value>\\d+) (?<currency>[^\\s]+) to (?<targetcurrency>[^\\s]+)";

var results = Regex.Match(str, regex);
if (results.Success)
{
    var value = results.Groups["value"].Value; //parse it int/float as you need to
    var currency = results.Groups["currency"].Value;
    var targetCurrency = results.Groups["targetcurrency"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

For this kind of problem I would'nt use regular expressions because you are parsing different 'tokens' (such as 'euro' '$', 'mkd') which differ in each string. Instead, you should use a simple parsing function that splits the string into its parts and then you recognize each 'token'. This method is much more flexible if the complexity increases.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String first = "20 $ to euro";

        String[] result = first.Split(null);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result[i]);

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0: getCurrencyValue(result[i]); break;
                case 1: parseCurrencyFrom(result[i]); break;
                case 2: parseCurrencyTo(result[i]); break;
            }

        }

    }

    public void parseCurrencyTo(String currencyCode)
    {
        switch (currencyCode)
        {
            case "euro": stuff(); break;
            case "$": stuff() break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the question, the asker is asking for a regular expression!

Comment: Yes but surely on stack overflow we look for the best solution to an answer, not simply a direct response to what is asked? Sometimes a commonsense answer can be far more effective..and then sometimes not, but better to have the options ey

Comment: Regex is the best answer. Splitting a string is less explicit and often more error prone. A single regex can mutate to cover edge cases (grammar change) in a single statement. How would splitting react to '£s' (not the s). A regex would be able to shave this off, splitting requires more tedious string manipulation code.

Comment: "I would'nt use regular expressions because you are parsing different 'tokens' (such as 'euro' '$', 'mkd') which differ in each string" To me that seems like exactly the situation where a regular expression *would* be appropriate; you want to match a string with a specific format, but variable parts to it.

Comment: Worth adding that, by explicitly requesting a regex, the question may be illustrating very real boundaries to their implementation, for example, their boss requires regex implementations.

Comment: @Gusdor s/boss/customer and it's because of on-site configurability and it suddenly becomes a lot less negotiable.